# How to translate c# Task to Unity coroutine (OnCollisionEnter2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

help to translate this code in coroutine. Im making game in unity and need to creat coroutine for it. I try made it, but it doesnt works.

```
        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("player") && collision.contacts[0].normal.y > 0.5f)
            {
                Instantiate(block, objectspawn.position, objectspawn.rotation);
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
                 _coin.Play();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, why do you need to translate collision code to coroutine? Please provide the necessary research and information to better understand your question. [This link will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("player") && collision.contacts[0].normal.y > 0.5f)
            {
                StartCoroutine(CreateBlock());

            }

IEnumerator CreateBlock(){
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
Instantiate(block, objectspawn.position, objectspawn.rotation);
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
                 _coin.Play();
}
```

Comment: thaks, i made it